# When should Passenger, Unicorn, and Rack be used?

Tags: linux, python, puppet, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Reading about Puppet often [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/), [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/), and [Rack](http://rack.github.io/) are mentioned, but I can't figure out what the purpose of these are. The website for Passenger says:

> Phusion Passenger is a web server and application server for Ruby
>   (Rack) and Python (WSGI) apps. It allows you to run your web apps with
>   the least amount of hassle, by taking care of pretty much all of the
>   heavy lifting for you when it comes to managing your apps' processes
>   and resources.

But why would I want to introduce a new piece of software, when Ruby have its own web server?

Can anyone give an example what problem these solves?

Comment: This question is really a research problem -- the answer is "You use Passenger, Unicorn, and Rack in situations where they make sense - solving a particular problem or filling a specific need in your environment". The documentation for these tools indicate what they do very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `puppet`, the reason is simply [scalability](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/scaling.html).

The embedded webserver used by the `puppetmaster` service has known limitations, therefore, when you need to provide service for more than ~10 nodes, it is very likely that you need to use something else.

The usual approach is to deactivate the `puppetmaster` service and create a virtual host in your web server listening on the 8140 TCP port, and use [`passenger`](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/passenger.html), which can handle the ruby code directly instead.

You can find an example configuration in the link above.